# Xcode Parse Query button Delete text and photo from a cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, parse-platform, swift4

each cell displays the according comments and photo of the user logged-on. They are loaded with parse.

[image]

Now you want to Löschen the button deletes the photo and the comments.

Unfortunately this does not work. Wen I click on the button nothing happens

Unfortunately I understand little of swift and can't get on the solution

The query works, and the app displays the photos and Commons.The query and post code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
super.viewDidLoad()
let query = PFQuery(className: "Post")

query.whereKey("username", equalTo: PFUser.current()?.username)
query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (object, error) in

    if let posts = object {
        for post in posts{
            print(posts)

            self.comments.append(post["message"] as! String)
            self.imageFile.append(post["imageFile"] as! PFFile)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }


        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()

        }
    }
})
```

}

And here of the "delete"function code that I have tried:

```
   @IBAction func remove(_ sender: Any) {
    print("Entered remove")
    let query = PFQuery(className: "Post")
    query.whereKey("username", equalTo: PFUser.current()?.username)
    query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (object, error) in

        if let posts = object {
            print(posts)
            for post in posts{
                print(posts)

                if let message = post["message"] as? String, let image = post["imageFile"] as? PFFile {
                    print("message and image read", message, image)
                    if let messageIndex = self.comments.index(of: message), let imageIndex = self.imageFile.index(of:image) {
                        self.comments.remove(at: messageIndex)
                        self.imageFile.remove(at: imageIndex)

                    }
                }

                self.tableView.reloadData()

            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    })
}
```

The output:

[image]

I don't get an error message and nothing is deleted.
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have access to your current index where and object ids.
So based on that you can remove easy.

The more easy way to implement the delete function is to have an array of objectId for your messages:

```
self.ids.append(post.objectId)
```

And when you want to delete it:

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "Post")
query.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: self.ids.index(of: indexPath.row))
// Make a query in background to only get the object that you want to delete 
query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock {
  (object: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
  if error != nil || object == nil {
    print("The getFirstObject request failed.")
  } else if let object = object {
    print("Successfully retrieved the object.")
    object.deleteInBackground()
  }
}
```

> Having different arrays representing the same object is not really good to do. So a better way to handle you problem is have only one array for your post

When you fetch it you can do something like that:

```
guard let user = PFUser.current() else { return }
let query = PFQuery(className: "Post")
query.whereKey("username", equalTo: user.username)
query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (posts, error) in
    if let posts = posts {
        self.posts = posts
    }
})
```

With this way when you want to delete it in the remove function:

```
if indexPath.row < self.posts.count {
    self.posts[indexPath.row].deleteInBackground()
}
```